# How to convert input lists to string in python

Tags: python, string, list, converters

```
L = [1,2,3]       

q = " ".join(str(x) for x in L)

print(q)

# as you see input is = L = [1,2,3]

# when you run the code output = 1 2 3
```

but when I want to use this code like this :

```
L = input("Enter your lst: ")
     
q = " ".join(str(x) for x in L)

print(q)

# I enter my input again = [1,2,3]

# and the output is = [ 1 , 2 , 3 ]

# but I was looking for this : 1 2 3
```

what is the problem here? what should I do to get the True output and convert input lists to string?

I am amatuar in coding so simple explanation would be better.

Comment: In `L = input("Enter your lst: ")`, `L` is already a string

Comment: @python_user yes of course

Comment: Enter only numbers without brackets. commas and spaces to get your desired output

Comment: Ask yourself (and read the official docs!), what does `input` statement return? HINT: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input

Comment: @IronFist I just want to know why this happened!

Comment: @python_user I just want to know why this happened!

Comment: @TheEpic, when you enter `[1, 2, 3]`, `L` will be a string equal to  `[1, 2, 3]`, so you are joining all the character of this string, not only the numbers

Comment: You should be kind to The Epic, he pointed to the documentation which answers your question in the first two sentences. The `input` function returns a string by default.

Comment: @IronFist I dont want change the input . how can I solve this problem without changing the input?

Comment: @WolVes so Is there any solution for this without changing the input? Is there any special code?

Comment: @TheEpic, the answer below is the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input()` returns a string in python. You'd need to convert the result of `input()` to a `list` and then pass it in.

If the user inputs the list as a comma separated values (e.g. "1,2,3"), then we can parse the data like this:

```py
inputdata = input("Enter your lst: ")
valueList = [v.strip() for v in inputdata.split(",")]
     
result = " ".join(valueList)

print(result)
```

Comment: Good . thank you bro . just one thing now the result that I got is = [1 2 3] and can I remove " [ ] " this thing too ?

Comment: You can trim it reliably using `strip()` to remove any trailing whitespace, and then slicing: `inputdata = input("Enter your lst: ").strip()[1:-1]`